# Format multiplication result to 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, jquery, currency

I'm having some weird behaviour with formatting money in javascript. I've read up and tried using multiple methods from [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_number_methods.asp) with varying degrees of luck and can't quite get my expected outcome.

Here's what I'm doing. I have an `<input>` where the user can input the quantity of an item, say they want 5 of X, and each X costs £19.34 (unit price).

Currently I'm doing it with an on change function, but that shouldn't matter.

Here's what I'm getting compared to what I should be getting:

5 x £19.34 =
I'm getting: `£96.7`, I want: `£96.70`

6 x £19.34 =
I'm getting: `£116.03999999999999`, I want: `£116.04`

3 x £19.34 =
I'm getting: `£58.019999999999996`, I want: `£58.02`

With the above examples this is the code I have:

```
$('.js_qty').change(function () {
  qty = $(this).val()
  $('#price').text(qty * unitPrice.toFixed(2))
});
```

This line in particular doesn't seem to be giving me the expected result:

```
unitPrice.toFixed(2)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `toFixed(2)` on the result of the multiplication, not directly on the `unitPrice`:

```js
var unitPrice = 19.34;

$('.js_qty').change(function() {
  var qty = $(this).val();
  $('#price').text((qty * unitPrice).toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="js_qty">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
<div id="price"></div>
```